# Calculate difference between two time stamps

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to calculate the difference between two separate times and assign that value to the previous state. So if I have a row in the table that shows 8 am with a state of "starved" and the next row shows 830 am with a state of "running" I need to be able to show a 3rd column that assigns the 30 minutes of starved time to the starved row in the first column. Is that possible.

This is an image of the current 2 columns and where I am trying to calculate the difference.

[image: This is an image of the current 2 columns and where I am trying to calculate the difference.]

Comment: Please add a code that you have already tried, help the community understand what efforts you have already made, this will allow the community to make required corrections in your code.

Comment: **Consumable** sample data and expected results will also help us help you. Images aren't consumable, unless you expect us to transcribe it (which you should not).

Comment: 8AM  does exist in your image. It's a bit of a problem to write that you want "this" when there is no supporting data. A consistent description of your issue and a MVCE will encourage others to help you.

Comment: Ok.. I apologize. I am not a sql person, so I have no idea what consumable sample data means, and I have not tried any previous code because I dont know the language itself. 8 AM was just a for instance.. anyway thank you for your time. I will research other avenues. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a try at this.  The first job was to get your data into some sort of structure:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (t_stamp DATETIME, SanderRMT_StateChange VARCHAR(50), seconds_between_intervals INT);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:59.267', 'Running', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:53.260', 'Starved', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:26.223', 'Running', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:18.213', 'Starved', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:13.150', 'Running', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:04:11.103', 'Starved', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:03:54.073', 'Running', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:03:48.067', 'Starved', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:03:31.007', 'Running', NULL;
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '20200130 06:03:13.907', 'Starved', NULL;
```

I think what you are asking is that we work with tuples, where each tuple begins with a "Starving" row, and then we need to find the next "Running" row, work out the time interval, and write this back to the "Starving" row.

If this isn't what you want then showing your desired results set might help?

```
--Organise the data into timestamp order
WITH x AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp DESC) AS order_id
    FROM
        @table)
--Update the starved rows with the time intervals
UPDATE
    t2
SET
    seconds_between_intervals = DATEDIFF(SECOND, t2.t_stamp, t1.t_stamp)
FROM
    x x1
    INNER JOIN @table t1 ON t1.t_stamp = x1.t_stamp AND t1.SanderRMT_StateChange = 'Running'
    INNER JOIN x x2 ON x2.order_id = x1.order_id + 1
    INNER JOIN @table t2 ON t2.t_stamp = x2.t_stamp AND t2.SanderRMT_StateChange = 'Starved';
```

You could probably use `LAG` or `LEAD` to do this more efficiently?

Results are:

```
t_stamp SanderRMT_StateChange   seconds_between_intervals
2020-01-30 06:04:59.267 Running NULL
2020-01-30 06:04:53.260 Starved 6
2020-01-30 06:04:26.223 Running NULL
2020-01-30 06:04:18.213 Starved 8
2020-01-30 06:04:13.150 Running NULL
2020-01-30 06:04:11.103 Starved 2
2020-01-30 06:03:54.073 Running NULL
2020-01-30 06:03:48.067 Starved 6
2020-01-30 06:03:31.007 Running NULL
2020-01-30 06:03:13.907 Starved 18
```

Answer (score -2):

**For MySQL**
The **TIMESTAMPDIFF** is the native MySQL function which returns the difference between two given timestamps (one timestamp is subtracted from the other) for the specified date part interval (seconds, days, weeks, etc.). The value returned is an INTEGER, the number of these intervals between the two timestamps.

**Note:** If end-date < start-date, **TIMESTAMPDIFF** returns a negative integer value.)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)
```

Examples:

```
mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2000-02-01 12:05:55 260','2003-05-01 12:05:55 267');
     > 1706400
```

For more, you can refer the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

**For Transact-SQL**

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Examples

```
DECLARE 
    @start_dt DATETIME2= '2019-12-31 23:59:59.9999999', 
    @end_dt DATETIME2= '2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000';


SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(year, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_year, 
    DATEDIFF(quarter, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_quarter, 
    DATEDIFF(month, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_month, 
    DATEDIFF(dayofyear, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_dayofyear, 
    DATEDIFF(day, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_day, 
    DATEDIFF(week, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_week, 
    DATEDIFF(hour, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_hour, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_minute, 
    DATEDIFF(second, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_second, 
    DATEDIFF(millisecond, @start_dt, @end_dt) diff_in_millisecond;
```

Refer more in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Perhaps for MySQL but OP is using tsql / SQL Server. Nor does it account for the use of 2 (or more?) different rows for the computation.

Comment: The OP has tagged `sql-server`. Everything in this answer is about MySQL and is why it is receiving down votes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Smor and Larnu.
If it is tsql, then the query should be like this I think.
`DATEDIFF ( datepart , datetime_expr1 , datetime_expr2 )`